# querydsl Can't find a codec for class java.time.ZonedDateTime

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, jhipster, querydsl

On my jhipster project v5.7.1, i have added querydsl support in my pom

```
    ....
<dependency>
<groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
<artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
<version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
....
<plugin>
<groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>process</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
<processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

The following Q class is generated

```
import static com.querydsl.core.types.PathMetadataFactory.*;

import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.*;

import com.querydsl.core.types.PathMetadata;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Path;


/**
 * QTurno is a Querydsl query type for Turno
 */
@Generated("com.querydsl.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QTurno extends EntityPathBase<Turno> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1639543103L;

    public static final QTurno turno = new QTurno("turno");

    public final DateTimePath<java.time.Instant> dataInserimento = createDateTime("dataInserimento", java.time.Instant.class);

    public final DateTimePath<java.time.Instant> dataUltimaModifica = createDateTime("dataUltimaModifica", java.time.Instant.class);

    public final StringPath dominio = createString("dominio");

    public final DateTimePath<java.time.Instant> fineAttivita = createDateTime("fineAttivita", java.time.Instant.class);

    public final DateTimePath<java.time.Instant> finePausa = createDateTime("finePausa", java.time.Instant.class);

    public final StringPath id = createString("id");

    public final StringPath idBadge = createString("idBadge");

    public final NumberPath<Integer> idContratto = createNumber("idContratto", Integer.class);

    public final StringPath idUtente = createString("idUtente");

    public final DateTimePath<java.time.Instant> inizioAttivita = createDateTime("inizioAttivita", java.time.Instant.class);

    public final DateTimePath<java.time.Instant> inizioPausa = createDateTime("inizioPausa", java.time.Instant.class);

    public final StringPath modificatoDa = createString("modificatoDa");

    public final StringPath nomeContratto = createString("nomeContratto");

    public final StringPath nominativo = createString("nominativo");

    public final StringPath numBadge = createString("numBadge");

    public final StringPath sottoDominio = createString("sottoDominio");

    public final StringPath stato = createString("stato");

    public final NumberPath<Integer> totOreContratto = createNumber("totOreContratto", Integer.class);

    public final StringPath totOreFa = createString("totOreFa");

    public final StringPath totOreIa = createString("totOreIa");

    public final StringPath totOreTurno = createString("totOreTurno");

    public final DatePath<java.time.LocalDate> turnoDel = createDate("turnoDel", java.time.LocalDate.class);

    public QTurno(String variable) {
        super(Turno.class, forVariable(variable));
    }

    public QTurno(Path<? extends Turno> path) {
        super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }

    public QTurno(PathMetadata metadata) {
        super(Turno.class, metadata);
    }

}
```

Then i have modified my repository

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Repository
    public interface TurnoRepository extends  MongoRepository<Turno, String>,
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<QTurno>,
    QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QTurno> {
    ....
```

The problem is in my Resource when i try to query date fields with predicate like after, before, ecc. Only eq seems to work

```
    ....
    QTurno qTurno = new QTurno("turno");
    Predicate predicate = qTurno.turnoDel.after(turno.getTurnoDel()));        
    Iterable<QTurno> turnoDb = turnoRepository.findAll(predicate);
```

This is the error

```
        org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.time.ZonedDateTime.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:212)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeMap(DBObjectCodec.java:222)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:198)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encode(DBObjectCodec.java:130)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encode(DBObjectCodec.java:61)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
    at org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext.encodeWithChildContext(EncoderContext.java:91)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.writeValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:136)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:115)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:247)
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.addDocument(RequestMessage.java:197)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:151)
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:147)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:245)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:98)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:441)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:80)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:189)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:264)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:118)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:217)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:120)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:717)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:711)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:471)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:415)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:711)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:826)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:813)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.initializeCursor(DBCursor.java:877)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:144)
    at com.querydsl.mongodb.AbstractMongodbQuery.fetch(AbstractMongodbQuery.java:256)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QuerydslMongoPredicateExecutor.findAll(QuerydslMongoPredicateExecutor.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy159.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy159.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at it.olisistemstart.gp.gw1.tm.web.rest.TurnoResource.createTurno(TurnoResource.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:884)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:165)
    at it.olisistemstart.gp.gw1.tm.web.rest.TurnoResourceIntTest.createTurno(TurnoResourceIntTest.java:189)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
```

ZonedDateTime field are not present in my Turno class, i have changed to java.time.Instant instead
Can help me!Thanks